# This is much too slow

Tags: python, html, pynput

I have the following code working very nicely, but it is **WAY** too slow - something like 3/4 of a second latency.  This is running on a Raspberry Pi 3+ under Raspbian Stretch with chromium browser as the client and apache2 as the server, both on the same Pi.  There is a 5" monitor, but no keyboard or mouse attached.  The unit has four momentary switches attached to GPIO pins, and each of the buttons controls a cursor.  Two of the buttons move the cursor image up and down, and the other two control the text on top of the cursor image.  After each button press, I issue a keypress (F5, in the code below) to the browser using pynput.keyboard.  I am sure the reason this is too slow is at the moment I am refreshing the entire screen after updating control values in files in /run/thermostat.  A better solution would be to emulate UpArrow and DnArrow to have the highlight image moved or the text updated, as the case may be.  Sending the appropriate control code is easy, but how do I move the image or change the text without doing a full page refresh?  (Note, this would also allow me to use the keyboard from an external browser to do the same thing.)

Snippet of external Python script that monitors the button status:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time, os
from pins import pinsarrow
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard = Controller()
...
def my_callback4(channel):
        Exists = os.path.exists('/run/thermostat/Cursor') # Check to see Cursor position is set
        if Exists:
                Fsize = os.path.getsize('/run/thermostat/Cursor') # Check for a valid file
                if Fsize == 0:
                        Write_Cursor(0)
                Cursor = Read_Cursor()
                if Cursor > 0:
                        Cursor = Cursor - 1
                        Write_Cursor(Cursor)      # Write the new Cursor position
##################################################
                        keyboard.press(Key.f5)   #
                        keyboard.release(Key.f5) #
##################################################
        else:
                Write_Cursor(0)                  # File does not exist.  Write the Cursor file.
GPIO.add_event_detect(pinsarrow[0], GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback1, bouncetime=100)  
GPIO.add_event_detect(pinsarrow[1], GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback2, bouncetime=100)
GPIO.add_event_detect(pinsarrow[2], GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback3, bouncetime=100)
GPIO.add_event_detect(pinsarrow[3], GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback4, bouncetime=100)
```

Snippet of Python code that creates the web page:

```
Exists = os.path.exists('/run/thermostat/Cursor') # Check to see the Cursor position has been set
if Exists:
        Fsize = os.path.getsize('/run/thermostat/Cursor')
        if Fsize > 0:
                with open("/run/thermostat/Cursor","r") as f: # Get the Cursor position
                        Cursor = int(f.read())
        else:
                write_Cursor()  # No value in Cursor file
else:
        write_Cursor()  # Cursor file does not exist

RunStatus = ["Heating On", "Cooling On", "Fan On", "Idle"]

print('Content-type: text/html\n')
print("\n")
with open("/usr/lib/cgi-bin/index.txt","r") as f:
        x = f.read()
        print(x)
######################################################################
## Places the cursor image at a position specified by variable Cursor#
######################################################################
print('<img src="/images/Thermostat-Cursor.png" width="100" height="29" style="position: absolute; left: 15px; top: ',65 + 30 * Cursor,'px;">', sep='')

############################################################
## Check for cursor position and set color text accordingly#
############################################################
bColor = ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
for x in range(0, 7):
        if Cursor == x:
                bColor[x] = "black"
        else:
                bColor[x] = "rgb(200,200,200)"
## Print each <div> with appropriate color
print('<div style="color:',bColor[0],'" class="Scale">',ClassValues[0][LineValue[0]],'</div>', sep="")
print('<div style="color:',bColor[1],'" class="Clock">',ClassValues[1][LineValue[1]],'</div>', sep="")
print('<div style="color:',bColor[2],'" class="Barometer">',ClassValues[2][LineValue[2]],'</div>', sep="")
print('<div style="color:',bColor[3],'" class="Server">',ClassValues[3][LineValue[3]],'</div>', sep="")
print('<div style="color:',bColor[4],'" class="Control">',ClassValues[4][LineValue[4]],'</div>', sep="")
if LineValue[4] < 2:
        print('<div style="color:',bColor[5],'" class="Hot">Cool: ',ClassValues[5],'</div>', sep="")
if LineValue[4] == 0 or LineValue[4] == 2:
        print('<div style="color:',bColor[6],'" class="Cold">Heat: ',ClassValues[6],'</div>', sep="")
```

Comment: Probably not the source of your timing issue, but all of your `f.close()` statements can be removed - that is what the `with` statement does for you. By using `with open(… etc.` the opened file handle is automatically closed when leaving the scope of the `with` statement, even if by a return or raised exception.

Comment: I see, thanks.  You are correct it is definitely not the cause of the latency.  Opening and closing these tiny files (less than 64 bytes) on an SSD only takes a few microseconds.  Nonetheless, I will remove the unnecessary close() calls.